# How to use cursor.callproc function with kparams for postgres procedure

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a postgres procedure for adding users into the user table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.add_user(
p_name character varying,
p_secondname character varying,
p_description character varying,
p_extid integer,
p_carid character varying)

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE var_userid integer;
    BEGIN
    
        INSERT INTO users ("name", "secondname", "description", "extid") 
        VALUES (p_name, p_secondname, p_description, "p_extid" )  RETURNING "id" INTO var_userid;
    
        IF p_carid IS NOT NULL 
        THEN    
        
            INSERT INTO user_to_cam (userid, carid)
            SELECT var_userid,c::INTEGER FROM regexp_split_to_table(p_carid, ';') AS c;     
        END IF; 
    
    END
$BODY$;
```

is it possible to use cursor.callproc() to add users like:

```
cursor.callproc('add_user', {'name':'Bob','secondname':'Dummy','description':'Some description','extid':'1','carid':'1',})
```

Comment: Which connection package are you using?

Comment: @Ilya Babkov: I dont know which backend is used by django, but according to the [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=callproc#cursor.callproc), `psycopg2` can handle dicts: *Named parameters can be used by supplying the parameters as a dictionary.*

Comment: @snakecharmerb i'm using django.db connection